# How to make azure devops release pipeline deploy into a stage only if new version of the artifact comes?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release pipeline that deploys multiple components using multiple stages. With the current setup i have if a release pipeline triggers then deployment happens in all stages even if new version of artifact is not generated.
My requirement is, deployment into stage should happen only if new version of artifact is generated i.e., out of 10 components if only one component got new version of artifact then the stage respective to that should only triggered and other components should be skipped.

FYI:
i don't want to create separate release pipelines for the components

Answer (score 0):

I think the condition of the tasks should be able to achieve your requirements.

Just give an idea, for example, if you publish new artifact to DevOps feed, you can use this REST API to get the packages versions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-package-versions?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Then, you can compare the latest version that the REST API returned with the artifact version in your release pipeline.

`condition: and(succeeded(), eq(<version in pipeline>, <latest version in feed>))`

You can refer to this official document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Hi, when i say artifact i mean the build artifacts not the artifact from azure feed and also i understood that we have to add a condition to agent job like u mentioned to achieve the requirement but issue here is i was unable to find a variable to get the version/build_number used for previous release.

Answer (score 0):

If you have continuous deployment triggers enabled for an artifact, the pipeline creates a new release (with all stages) every time. Since the build artifact trigger is abstracted away from the stages, you can't select a stage per artifact.

You said you didn't want to create a separate pipeline per artifact but that really sounds like the correct design. That way only the associated stage(s) will be deployed when the artifact is updated.